# The set of differentiable functions $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ whose domains include a given point $m\in M$ doesn't form an algebra?!

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am reading the book "Differentiable Manifolds" by Brickell and Clark.

on page 54, it  is written that:If we denote the set of differentiable functions $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ on a manifold $M$ whose domains include a given point $m\in M$ by $\mathcal{F}(m)$, then $\mathcal{F}(m)$ does not form a vector space over the set of real number $\mathbb{R}$. And that is because $\mathcal{F}(m)$ does not contain a function $-f$ such that $f + (-f) = 0$ for all $f\in \mathcal{F}(m)$!

I'm confused a little bit. Because if a function $f$ is defined at a point $m\in M$, then $-f$ is also defined at $m$. Am i making a mistake?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That looks like a strange statement. I would think that _any_ function $f:M\to \Bbb R$ had _all_ points $m\in M$ in their domain by definition.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the domain of $f + (-f)$ will be the domain of $f$. But the zero function is defined on all of $M$, so that $f + (-f)$ will not necessarily be the zero function.

Comment: Let me guess. Next things he does is define *germs*, or equivalence classes of functions that coincide in a neighborhood of $m$, right?

Comment: @Claudius yeah, it is correct. I did not pay attention to this point at all. Thank you so much.

Comment: @  Giuseppe Negro No, then they defined derivations without using germs or equivalence classes on this set of functions.

Comment: I don't follow. Isn't $-f$ and $0$ both differentiable functiions on $M$?! And why wouldn't $f+(-f)=0$?

Comment: @WilliamMcGonagall Per Claudius' comment, the sum of functions $f+g$ has domain $dom(f)\cap dom(g)$. But this means that if $dom(f)$ isn't all of $M$, then $dom(f+(-f))\not=M$ either. So $f+(-f)$ isn't the zero function, since the zero function is defined on *all* of $M$. It is a "sub-function" (= *restriction*) of the zero function, but it's not literally the same thing.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Please excuse my ignorance. Does the term "domain" have a different meaning than the usual one? The OP says that $\mathcal F(m)$ is the set of all *"differentiable functions $f:M\to\mathbb R$..."*. Isn't the domain of every function in this set $M$?

Comment: @WilliamMcGonagall The book the OP is using appears to be using partial functions. I.e., they appear to define a differentiable function $f:M\to\Bbb{R}$ to be a pair $(U,f)$, with $U\subseteq M$ open and $f:U\to \Bbb{R}$ an ordinary differentiable function. As far as I'm aware, this is quite uncommon, but it's not unreasonable. Though in my personal opinion, it is poor style. (Except possibly for pedagogical purposes, as one does with high schoolers in the usual curriculum in the states). Thus the domain of a differentiable function $(U,f) : M\to \Bbb{R}$ is the set $U$ rather than $M$.

Comment: could it be that here they might call domain what in other places is referred to as support? then everything would make sense.

Comment: @Enkidu no, if the domain was the support, then we would always have $f + (-f) = 0$ and there would be no confusion. The convention in the book mentioned by the OP is exactly the one that jgon suggested.

Comment: there would be  no zero as $0$ has empty support

Comment: Ah, of course! So this renders my first point moot. But the second point still stands.